# How to check for record which has no entry in another table with some specific value?

Tags: query

For example, if we have two tables: Table1 and table 2

Table1 - main table (with unique entry for all records)
table2 - is a history table(where is containg many entries for same record on time stampe basis) (also contains some specific field type)

I need to retreive data like, all data from table1 where there is no entry for the record with type = 'Some vaue'

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site. Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle)? Also please add some sample data and expected output as well as table definitions. Please see [help us help you](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/)

Comment: What have you tried? What was the result, and how was it different from what you'd expected?

Answer (score 7):

I typically write this as NOT EXISTS query because this aligns with the wording of the problem ("find everything in table1 where no corresponding row exists in table2")

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1
where not exists (select *
                  from table2 t2
                  where t1.id = t2.table1_id
                    and type = 'Some Value');
```

Depending on your DBMS, mcNets' solutions might be faster - that depends a lot on the query optimizer, in Oracle for example it won't make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you could use a LEFT JOIN to get all records from table1 and then play with IS NULL and IS NOT NULL to get all existing and not existing related values in table2.

```
SELECT table1.id
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table2.table1_id = table2.id
WHERE
    table2.table1.id is null
```

You can also use GROUP BY and COUNT() > 0 or COUNT() = 0

```
SELECT table1.id, count(table2.table1_id) as records_in_table2
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table2.table1_id = table1.id
GROUP BY 
    table1.id
HAVING 
    COUNT(table2.table1_id) > 0
```